# Linked List - Remove numbers from a specified range

Tags: algorithm

I have a linked list that contains numbers from 0 to 1 and my task is to remove numbers from a given range (x, y) from this list. Do you have any idea how to solve that problem in a reasonable complexity?

Comment: A better suited data structure would be a sorted one, if that is possible, or even a `Set` variant like `HashSet`.

Comment: Any attempt or code you have ?

Comment: Do you want to solve this problem for a specific language like **Java** or **C++**? If so please also add the corresponding tag.

Comment: No, I don't have to solve that in any specific language. I was looking for a pure algorithm :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you think about it, linkedlist has no method getAtIndex. You can only start from Head and work your way to the tail or vice versa. The complexity of this would be O(n)

Comment: So I have to check all the elements, right? Are you sure there isn't any faster algorithm that uses properties which are specific for a linkedlist? I'm sorry if I sound like a noob, but I'm still learning. :)

Comment: If the task is not limited to just LinkedList, I would use other data structure. If the task was only to locate the index of lower and upper limit in a sorted list. You could do this in `log(n)`

Answer (score 4):

Let's first think about how a `LinkedList` is structured. Lets take a look at the following image:

[image: Doubly Linked List structure]
Each element in a (doubly) linked list has a pointer to the next (and the previous) element. The Java class `LinkedList` is for example a **doubly-linked list**.

In such a list there is no direct access to "*give me the index of **element B***". We just have a `head` reference (pointing at the start of the list) and a `tail` reference (pointing at the end). To find the **element B**, we need to start at `head` (or `tail`) and completely walk through the entire list, following the `next` (or `prev`) pointer of the elements until we found **element B**.

---

So, back to your question, there is no efficient way to remove elements of `range(x, y)` from a `LinkedList`. This can only be done efficient in sorted structures like `PriorityQueue` or a sorted `ArrayList` (**binary search** yields `O(log(n)`) or one with direct access to elements like `HashSet` for example.

---

Here is a code snippet in **Java** that solves your task for `LinkedList`, however, as stated, it is not efficient and has a running time of `O(n)` (we need to take a look at each element in order to find out which elements need to be deleted):

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = ...

// Inclusive lower bound
int lowerBound = ...
// Exclusive upper bound
int upperBound = ...

ListIterator<Integer> listIter = list.listIterator();
while (listIter.hasNext()) {
    int value = listIter.next();

    // Check if the value is inside bounds
    if (value >= lowerBound || value < upperBound) {
        // Remove the element from the list using the iterator
        // which prevents ConcurrentModificationException
        listIter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an exhaustive answer. It's a task from my university algorithm course. That answer seemed too obvious for me, so I started to think if there is any faster solution. I see that actually there isn't.

Comment: Yep, that kind of problem is definitely not for which `LinkedList` was designed for. Its advantage is that you can easily remove elements from within, or add them. Also and advantage is that the elements itself can be arbitrarily placed inside the memory, the memory for all elements does not need to be connected as it must in an Array for example.